# Using scripts written in c# code in javascript breaks with error Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, c#

My Action

From this action method I am returning javascript code in a viewbag and in my view I am using this javascript to render it.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
                var js = "$(document).ready(function(){ " +
                            "alert('Test Verbatim string'); " +
                        "});";

            ViewBag.JavaScrpt = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(js);
            return View();
        }
```

View code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @ViewBag.JavaScrpt
</script>
```

I am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
And rendered javacript code in browser is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ alert(\u0027Test Verbatim string\u0027); });
</script>
```

I know this is not good practice to write javascript code in C#. But I need it for specific requirement.

Comment: remove `{` before alert

Comment: Clearly, whatever templating system you're using (I assume some Microsoft MVC or ASP.Net thing) is replacing `'` with `\u0027`. So you need to look at the documentation for that system and find out how to tell it not to do that.

Comment: just don't encode the javascript...... just use `@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.JavaScript)`. BTW your example is full of typos...

Answer (score -2):

You have an extra "{" bracket before your alert call.

Comment: That's *one* problem.

Comment: I put it by mistake. It is not the actual issue

Comment: @TBAG script tag that you have shared also shows same error. Can you check if your rendered js is valid?

Comment: @Rajesh randered javascript I have included in code

Comment: @TBAG as said by @T.J. Crowder, something is changing `'` to \u0027. Try putting the text in a variable and pass that variable.

Comment: Tried its not fixing issue.